# Java SAX parser, How do I prevent character references entirely? (DoS attack)

Tags: java, xml, saxparser, denial-of-service, character-reference

The XML files of incoming request needs to be validated. One requierement is that character references are prevented entirely because of possible DoS attacks. If I configure the `SAXParserFactory` like below:

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spf.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);
```

then the parer still resolves 100.000 entity expansions.

```
The parser has encountered more than "100.000" entity expansions in this document; this is the limit imposed by the application.
```

The prevention of external references was done via an `EntityResolver` which works fine. But how do I prevent the character references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character references cannot cause a denial of service attack, so there is no reason to prevent them.

Comment: But what in case of a RESTful service, which handles the request according to FIFO. If a request takes much longer beaucse of the entity expansion, all other request are delayed.
Isn't it a kind of Dos?

Comment: If a XML file contains about 10^7 entity characters, the processing takes several minutes until a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` occurs.

Comment: What are "entity characters"? I suspect you're using incorrect terminology regarding entity references and character references, and we are therefore talking at cross-purposes. Character references are of the form `&#xa;` or `&#10;` and cause no network traffic or significant performance overheads.

Comment: Thank you. And yes, I'm talking about character references. But if the service receives the following XML `<!DOCTYPE foo [
<!ENTITY a "1234567890" >
<!ENTITY b "&a;&a;&a;&a;&a;&a;&a;&a;&a;&a;" > ... <!ENTITY j "&i;&i;&i;&i;&i;&i;&i;&i;&i;&i;" > ... <Foo>&j;</Foo> ...`
The processing of this request takes several seconds and all further requests are queued. For me this is a classical DoS, or do we talk about different things?

Comment: `&a;` is not a character reference, it is an entity reference.

Comment: Sorry, I'm here again. Can you please tell me how the different types of entity refernces are called: 
1) `<!ENTITY a "1234567890" >`
2) `<!ENTITY ref SYSTEM "http://example.com/file.xml">`
3) `<!ENTITY ref SYSTEM "file:///etc/shadow/">`

Or are the all together simply called `Entity References` ?

Comment: None of these are entity references. An example of an entity reference is `&ref;`. These are entity declarations. The first one is a declaration of an internal entity, numbers 2 and 3 are external entities: more precisely, external general parsed entities.

Answer (score 0):

An instance of `org.apache.xerces.util.SecurityManager` can limit the amount of entity expansions. Here's the an example.

```
SAXParser saxParser = spf.newSAXParser();
org.apache.xerces.util.SecurityManager mgr = new org.apache.xerces.util.SecurityManager();
mgr.setEntityExpansionLimit(-1);
saxParser.setProperty("http://apache.org/xml/properties/security-manager", mgr);
```

With this, the parsing process terminates if the XML file contains at least one entity reference. Now there's no more need for an `EntityResolver`.

The jar file which contains the `SecurityManager` can be downloaded [here](http://www.findjar.com/jar/xerces/jars/xercesImpl-2.7.1.jar.html?all=true).